# if and else statement condition values not being recognized

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a block of code that takes a users input value and compares it to a random number generated when the page loads. Right now the if statement in the guess function is displaying regardless of what the value of the conditions are. If they are true it displays the first and third message and if it is wrong it also displays those two. What changes should I make to my code in order to get the if statement to alert the correct response in correlation with the users input value.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", setup);
            void setup(); {
            var rNumber1 = Math.random(1-100);
            var rNumber = Math.floor(rNumber1);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <table>
                <tr><td><label>Enter Guess:</label></td><td><input id="guessedNumber" type="text" /></td></tr>
                <tr><td><label>Is Correct?: </label></td><td><label id="guessResult"></label></td></tr>
                <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td><button type="button" onclick="guess()">Submit Guess</button></td></tr>
            </table>
        </form>
        <script>
            function guess() {
                var guessedNumber = document.getElementById("guessedNumber");
                if (guessedNumber != rNumber) {
                alert("Your guess is incorrect. Try Again!");
                } else if (guessedNumber == NaN) { 
                    alert("Please enter a valid Number");
                } else (guessedNumber == rNumber) 
                    alert("You guessed correctly!");
                }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `guessedNumber` is a DOM node, not a number

Comment: Also your random number will always be `0`

Comment: Why do people frequently think the problem is with `if/else`, when it's actually with the values they're comparing? All you need is a simple `console.log(guessedNumber, rNumber)` to see what they are.

Comment: that's not how `Math.random()` works in Javascript. It doesn't take any parameters and always returns a number between 0 and 1

Comment: also also, `else` does not take a condition so `else (guessedNumber == rNumber)` is invalid. It should just be `} else {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
var guessedNumber = document.getElementById("guessedNumber").value;
```

Also, the `Math.random()` method always returns a value between 0 and 1 excluding 1. It takes no parameters. Moreover, the way you have passed it parameters using the - sign will subtract the former number from the latter. The way it is used to generate a random number from 1-100 is usually:

```
rNumber1 = (Math.random()*100+1)
```

It will multiply the number times 100 and adds 1 to it which ensures that you never get 0. Also, you won't get 101 because it returns a value between 0 and 1 excluding 1.

Answer (score 0):

get the value of from the input box using `.value`

also, i did not see any open parenthesis in the else statement, and removed the condition in else statement.

setup() is not defined anywhere so i dont know what you are trying to do with that

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            //window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", setup);
            //void setup(); {
            //var rNumber1 = Math.random(1-100);
            var rNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1
            //}
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <table>
                <tr><td><label>Enter Guess:</label></td><td><input id="guessedNumber" type="text" /></td></tr>
                <tr><td><label>Is Correct?: </label></td><td><label id="guessResult"></label></td></tr>
                <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td><button type="button" onclick="guess()">Submit Guess</button></td></tr>
            </table>
        </form>
        <script>
            function guess() {
              console.log(rNumber);
                var guessedNumber = parseInt(document.getElementById("guessedNumber").value);
                if (guessedNumber != rNumber) {
                  alert("Your guess is incorrect. Try Again!");
                } else if (guessedNumber == NaN) { 
                    alert("Please enter a valid Number");
                } else {
                    alert("You guessed correctly!");
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: FYI, `Please enter a valid Number` is unreachable. No value of `guessedNumber` will ever result in `guessedNumber == NaN`